# Instantiating priority_queue with deque does not compile - with vector it does. Why is that?

Tags: c++, vector, priority-queue, deque

In the below program **why does the construction with `deque` fail but the construction with `vector` is ok**?

Both provide the functions and the RandomAccess iterator expected by `priority_queue`. I do not see the reason.

I tested it for C++98, C++11 and C++14: [see test program](http://cpp.sh/8ruel)

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    deque<int> d; 
    priority_queue<int> q(d.begin(), d.end());

    vector<int> v; 
    priority_queue<int> q1(less<int>(), v); //compiles

    deque<int> d1; 
    priority_queue<int> q2(less<int>(), d1); //does not compile

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you can use c++17 then [deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/deduction_guides) [can determine it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ue6XSo4pjLAvM99f).

Comment: @apple [Sure?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5650f74d4fc52ea)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah, and my second link shows how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed to specify `deque<int>` as template parameter for `priority_queue`:

```
deque<int> d1; 
priority_queue<int,deque<int>> q2(less<int>(), d1); 
                // ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/beb1adc94a2a0748).

See the reference documentation of [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). `std::vector` is taken as default type parameter for the template:

> ```
> template<
>     class T,
>     class Container = std::vector<T>, // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>     class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> > class priority_queue;
> ```

That's why the other version compiles.